# What would be the British English equivalent to "The Elements of Style"?

Tags: british-english

I've been referred to this book by a lot of people, but one of the basic "rules" that it mentions - making your language more "cut and dry", which seems to be more of a thing with American English, whereas more complex sentence structure is commonplace in British English.

Essentially, I'm asking two questions:

- Is there a British English equivalent of *The Elements of Style*?
- Am  I correct in thinking that the type of writing advocated in that book is generally considered to be *substandard* or *uncommon* in the UK?

Comment: The grammar rules section of *The Elements of Style* is considered substandard by many in the US as well.

Comment: But mainly The Elements of Style is considered "American" rather than substandard.

Comment: @ DJClayworth Not by me.

Comment: 'The Cambridge Guide to English Usage'  – 29 Apr 2004 by Pam Peters  (Author).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a resource request

Comment: It's definitely substandard. Also definitely American. Though it emanates from an American professor of English, filtered through a talented but ignorant student.

Answer (score 16):

There is *[Fowler's Modern English Usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage)* for British English.  It is much longer than ***The Elements of Style***, however.

Though I have never used it personally, you may want to check out *[The Complete Plain Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Plain_Words)*.  That appears to be a much more concise, pamphlet-style guide to British English.

As far as your second question goes, I don't know of anybody (either in the US or UK) that thinks it is better to make your writing more difficult for readers. I probably cite this essay once a week on EL&U, but Orwell's *[Politics and the English Language](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/orwell46.htm)* is a small 'British' style guide in itself. Orwell puts forth several stylistic rules, or rather things to avoid in order to make ones writing more clear. I only bring it up because Orwell is British and he puts forth a great argument for clarity and simplicity in writing.

Fowler too advocated for clear writing ([see the section on 'Approach'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage)):

> Henry W. Fowler’s general approach to English usage was to encourage a direct, vigorous writing style, and to oppose all artificiality — firmly advising against unnecessarily convoluted sentence construction and the use of foreign words and phrases and archaisms. He opposed all pedantry, and notably ridiculed artificial grammar rules not warranted by natural English usage...

Comment: What about the second question?

Comment: Hmm... looks like *Fowler* has the same opinion. Is that the same for most of the UK?

Comment: It's not considered helpful to lose readers in a maze of twisty subclauses.  Experienced writers grow to know how rich and convoluted they can make their language, often depending on exactly who their audience is, but they get there by learning how to be brief and clear first.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of one, but from a quick scan, I think most of the guidance stands equally well in the UK...

Writing should be about communication not obfuscation, so following a few simple rules [Perhaps simple is the wrong word to use in relation to the English language, but...] and use of a good dictionary should be enough.

I can highly recommend:

"Eats, Shoots & Leaves: The Zero Tolerance Approach to Punctuation"

A book by Lynne Truss

[Available at all good book shops]

Comment: "Eats, Shoots & Leaves" only covers punctuation, not grammar or other matters. And the existence of this site indicates that English grammar and usage cannot be covered by "a few simple rules".

Comment: That's me told then...

Comment: It is a good book though.

Comment: ;-) .................